# Translation of these Cirth runes

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

What is the translation of what's written below?

I think it may be the poem of the One Ring, but I'm not sure.

[image: Angerthas script from Lord of the Rings]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## *The Lord of the Rings translated from the Red Book*

This is followed by the tengwar script at the bottom of the page

[image]

which transliterates to:

> *of Westmarch by John Ronald Reuel Tolkien; herein is set forth the history of the War of the Ring and the Return of the King as seen by the Hobbits*

according to one user on the [Tolkien forum](http://www.thetolkienforum.com/index.php?threads/runes.8327/).

I personally transliterated the Cirth using the guide in Appendix E in the Return of the King.

---

### The translation process.

Using the table from Appendix E, I got the following rune numbers for the runes:

`11, 55, 31, 50, 12, 9, 50, 4, 11, 55, 12, 39, 36(37), 35, 8, 12, 48, 22, 35, 31, 8, 9, 3, 12, 50, 6, 11, 55, 12, 46, 9, 2, 51, 18`

`dh, *, l, o, r, d, o, v, dh, *, r, i, n (ng*), s, t, r, a, n, s, l, t, d, f, r, o, m ,dh, *, r, e, d, b, ó, k`

Which with some imagination and reading of the surrounding texts of Appendix E breaks up nicely into:

> dh* lord ov dh* rins transltd from dh* red bók

since `dh` is the hard `th` sound in "the" (as opposed to the soft in "thin"), and the `v` the hard `f` in "of" (as opposed to say "flour", and finally the `ó` is the long o in "book" (as opposed to the short in "stock"). With that we can see that it should say:

> The Lord of the Rings translated from the Red Book

Comment: I tried translating using the Appendix E, but they couldn't be read and understood(random Gibberish)

Comment: Hmm, I've gotten rid of my working but I can provide it below if you'd like.

Comment: Worth noting that 55 and 56 were used by the Dwarves for the two (weak) vowels in *butter*, explaining the `*` for "the". Also, just as a point of interest, a raised dot is used as a word separator, although it's hard to see in some places unless you know it is supposed to be there.

Comment: Several runes are described has having separate values in the older Angerthas and the Angerthas Moria. Number 36 in particular, should be read using its later value `ŋ`. (Even later, apparently, a new rune 37 was created for `ng`, leaving 36 to be used as `n`.)

Comment: @chepner out of interest what are your sources for these details? Granted I haven’t read Appendix E in a while I can’t recall these details all too clearly

Comment: It's in the last 2 paragraphs of Appendix E.

Comment: Also, I've only given it a cursory glance, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirth looks like it gives good coverage of the various differences in meaning.

Comment: I’ll have to take a close look and update then!