# Can this be translated into English?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

[image]

Can this tattoo be translated into English?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not a translation service.

Comment: @AndresF. - there is [precedence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190151) for asking translation questions. This has also been discussed previously [on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8166/).

Comment: What is this tattoo and how is it Sci-Fi exactly?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about Science Fiction or Fantasy.

Comment: @fez I'll do my piece to revert that precedent. If enough people agree with me, it will stop being acceptable :)

Comment: I get that the community has for some reason decided this is a worthwhile question.  Let me note that while this _looks_ like Tengwar, it is at the very least mirrored.  (Which makes me think this is swiped from someone else's selfie taken in a mirror, which is a bit stalkerish...)  But even if it can be mirrored back to legible Tengwar glyphs, we don't know the mode.  One might guess Sindarin, but it's equally possible it's one of the real-world modes; the lack of vowels and diacritics makes this much harder.  Oh, and as a string of Tengwar consonants, it can be read rotated too.

Comment: Just as @DavidW has mentioned, those are Tengwar but horizontally mirrored. And the unmirrored version would be gibberish to Tolkien, Bilbo, and the Elves. I'll continue to create an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Those are Tengwar (Elvish Letters created by J.R.R. Tolkien) but horizontally mirrored.

The unmirrored version would be gibberish to Tolkien, Bilbo, and the Elves. I, however, can tell someone installed some Tengwar font on the computer, typed ***Cogito ergo sum*** and ended up with this tattoo (Or he typed *Cogito ergo sum*, then changed the font to Tengwar).

Here's the unmirrored tattoo and what I recreated in Notepad.
[image: unmirrored]

You see, that's not how the usual Tengwar fonts work. The Tengwar letters are NOT each mapped to a corresponding Latin letter, which is impossible because there are more than 26 Tengwar letters and "diacritics". What the tattooer did is comparable to typing Latin with the keyboard layout changed to Russian. You'll get the same gibberish (Сщпшещ укпщ ыгь), instead of the correct cyrillic transliteration (Когито эрго сум).

If an Elf from the Third Age tries to read it, he'll get:
"hwngsmhw fvnghw grhlh" something like that.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer probably won't be seen by many as the question was never bumped to the front page when you posted - thank you for proving that while it can technically be "translated" into something, it cannot be translated from Tengwar into anything meaningful.